# Slow Down Playback in Adobe After Effects

Tags: adobe, playback, ram, after-effects

I think is probably the wrong place so if you would like to point me to the right place that would be great.

But my question is: How do I slow down RAM play playback to about 25% with audio so i can get the timing right on some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most complete solution but you can go to Layer/Time/Enable Time Remapping on each of your layers to slow them down.